# Best way to link to other articles from the newsletter in a blog

Tags: navigation, hyperlinks, newsletter, blog

I am currently designing a new company blog and we are planning on having a monthly email newsletter.

My question is:
If someone clicks on one article from the email newsletter, what's the best way of showing them the other articles?

Is it a link at the bottom of the article?

As far as I can see no one really does this. They just link you off to the article and you have to return to the email to get the other articles.

Any thoughts would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One typical pattern is a **side panel, which contains recent or related posts**. Even if a user hadn't read the whole article (because of some reasons), he still could see and go to other articles. It isn't possible if such panel is below the article. Take a look at some examples:

[image]

.

[image]